Is a FRITZ!Box 7530 router (compatible with OpenWRT) will work for VoIP?
My VoIP wallsocket is very similar to this one:

I use a AVM FRITZ!Box 7490 router, with proprietary software which is near to EOL, but it works perfect with this cable:

This cable is a Y cable, one plug goes to phone, the other to internet (I don't know why is VoIP they use this configuration, I think VoIP use the standard VDSL port).
I want to know something:

The FRITZ!Box 7530 router (compatible with OpenWRT) will work for VoIP?
Do you know a good solution for use a VoIP router VDSL supported by OpenWRT?

Actually I have no problem with FritzBox, I want to know if an openwrt router will works, consider the "wallsocket" has two ports: one is for vdsl internet, other for phone (even I heard the fttc and voip can work with one port, why my isp give me two port wallsocket?)

Have you tried it? Note that the first image, of the wallsocket, is a modified image and not real life. VOIP is just a subset of regular networking. At home, you usually have internet coming in to the modem, and the modem serves the VOIP service out on its own RJ11 port (though that may vary). What you do with that VOIP signal coming doesn't really matter, just get it to your VOIP phone however you want.

Did you get this FritzBox from your ISP? Have you contacted them to see whether their proprietary firmware supports VOIP on that device? What ports does the Fritzbox have on it? Are any of the RJ11?

I have no problem with fritzBox, my question was another: if was possible to connect an openwrt router to this socket, and the most important thing, if voip will work.

I don't get it from my isp, i have buy it, and it works fine. Only one problem, now is EOL and I have to get a more secure router.

VOIP will be coming in over your ISPs line, regardless who you bought it from. Why your ISP gave you a 2 port jack is probably immaterial, but you'll need to ask them. Whether OpenWRT supports VOIP on that device is something you should be able to look up in the OpenWRT documentation.

Have you tested whether it’s compatible with VoIP?

No, I still don't have it, I considering to buy it if openwrt on 7490 fails or works bad.
